# How to check if a parameter has been passed

Tags: javascript

I'm passing parameters to a function in a JavaScript library I wrote:

```
ffff.setup({
    'size':{'width':'100','height':'100'}
});
```

In the function, I pick them up:

```
var ffff = {
    setup: function(config) {
        if (config["size"]["width"]) {my_width = config["size"]["width"];}
        if (config["size"]["height"]) {my_height = config["size"]["height"];}
    }
}
```

My error is, if I do not specify a parameter, I get a `Cannot read property 'height' of undefined` error: (the error occurs on `if (config["size"]["height"])`)

```
ffffr.setup({
    'size':{'width':'100'}
});
```

How should I detect if a variable has been provided or not?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I check whether a variable is defined in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/519145/how-can-i-check-whether-a-variable-is-defined-in-javascript)

Comment: Why do you need to assign them to local variables? You can just use the object. Also, are those supposed to be globals? Because you didn't declare them...

Comment: Where are you accessing `file`?

Comment: Holy cow that's a lot of answers in such a short time

Comment: 6+ answers and none suggest a mixin approach for setting defaults. I'm disappoint.

Comment: @Barmar 'file' was a variable I used in my full code.  Here it should read 'height'

Comment: I'd recommend checking [this approach](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7124960/1331430), just replace the `$.extend` with a deep extend algorithm.

Answer (score 4):

There may be more elegant approaches to this (such as jQuery extends() if you use that library), but at a very basic level you could just do

```
if(typeof config['size'] !== "undefined" && typeof config['size']['height'] !== "undefined")
```

Comment: There's really no point on doing the `typeof` check as the object surely exists, you could simply use the `in` operator like: `if ('size' in config && 'height' in config.size)`

Comment: @elclanrs seems to have the nicest fix.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking at the config object, you can use [`.hasOwnProperty`<sup>MDN</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)

```
if( config.hasOwnProperty("propName") ){
 //use config.propName
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (config.size && config.size.width) ...
```

Comment: or as @elclanrs said above: if ('size' in config && 'height' in config.size)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if (typeof variable === 'undefined') {
    // variable is undefined
}
```

Or:

```
if (typeof (conf) === 'object') {
    // object is undefined
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
config["size"].hasOwnProperty('width')
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if it is defined, and use a ternary operator to set a default

```
(param===undefined)?default_value:param;
```

what that will do is check if it is defined, and set it to whatever you want it to if it is undefined, but keep it the same otherwise